# A new TableView goes behind another TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I am new to IOS, my requirement is a slide menu on my view, I don't want use any third part libraries. So I tried these approaches 
1. Whenever a button is clicked I tried to add a view with a new TableView at X = -320 added as subview to my view and used like this

```
CGRect destination = self.view.frame;
if (destination.origin.x > 0) {
    destination.origin.x = 0;
} else {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:chat_table];
    destination.origin.x = 320;
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.view.frame = destination;

}];
```

this works fine but there is no user interaction  to that view or new TableView. I don't know why.
2.I tried to slide the existing tableview to right and show the slide view.
But the existing tableview has auto layout so after sliding it to right it comes back to same position. i tried removing constraints but it is messing up with all other auto layout constraints so I cant use this approach.
3. In this I added the slide View on to the existing view in this it shows like this

**It is like this now:**

[image]

**And It should be like:**

[image]

I tried sending views back and front

How to solve this?
Sorry for any bad English.
Thanks

Comment: May i know why you dont want to use a third party library ?, There are many good ones which are easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it guys, I was using :

```
 [self.view addSubview:slide_view];
```

I just changed it to :

```
 [[self.view superview] addSubview:slide_view];
```

Its working fine.